# Custom color settings in VS.NET editor for current line when in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm using a black syntax highlighting theme in my Visual Studio.NET which I like very much. When in debug mode and step-by-stepping through the code the current line background is yellow, which is Ok.

However the line of code up the stack that invoked the function I currently stepping through is also highlighted, in ugly gray background which makes white code unreadable.

I went twice through the list of items in Fonts and Colors settings but couldn't find anything that would remotely look like the item I'm looking for!

Help oh you mighty stack overflowers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! It's called "Read-Only Region" - VERY non-intuitive!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "Inactive Selected Text"?  I believe that is the one you are looking for.

Comment: let me try it... Nope! it's not.